# While trying to login, from server side I got 200 code, but in browser I got this error

Tags: jwt, mern

> Error: "error" is read-only     at _readOnlyError (readOnlyError.js:2)

```js
const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log("Login.js")
    if (isObjEmpty(errors)) {
      console.log("isObjEmpty:", isObjEmpty)
      // console.log("errors:", errors)

      useJwt
        .login({ email, password })
        .then(res => {
          console.log("res:", res)
          const data = { ...res.data.userData, accessToken: res.data.accessToken, refreshToken: res.data.refreshToken }
          dispatch(handleLogin(data))
          ability.update(res.data.userData.ability)
          console.log("data:", data)
          history.push(getHomeRouteForLoggedInUser(data.role))
          toast.success(
            <ToastContent name={data.fullName || data.username || 'John Doe'} role={data.role || 'admin'} />,
            { transition: Slide, hideProgressBar: true, autoClose: 2000 }
          )
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err))
    }
  }
```